# bash functions and scope in sh-5.0$

Tags: linux, bash

I tried to write my first bash function but run into an error.

```
test() {
$1=/home;
}
```

I expected the function to set any variable to /home.

Example expected:

```
test TEST
echo $TEST
/home
```

Example got:

```
test TEST
sh: TEST=/home: No such file or directory
echo TEST
```

Can you tell me how I get to my expected output and why I failed?

Comment: What is `1$` about? Are you sure your function is using `$1` or `1$`?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's using ```$1```. Edited my post to output off sh-5.0$

Comment: Don't you need to use an escape code instead of the forward slash as it gets interpreted differently?

Comment: The explicit error is one thing, but will ignore it for now. That said, I experimented a bit and believe you should read up on how Bash handles stuff [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16553089/117259) as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33376904/117259). The issue is that `$1` is a an argument value passed into the function `test()` and is not going to affect anything outside of the function. So assigning `$1=/home` will only affect the `$1` in the function; not outside of it. No easy way to change that. Also, you cannot dynamically assign variables that way; look at my first link.

Comment: So past that comment: This all seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/243319) where you are trying to script something to set a `/home` value for some reason, but unclear. And your approach here makes sense for a true programming language, but is painfully hard to deal with in Bash. So what exactly are you attempting to do here?

Comment: Using variable variable names is tricky, and usually a bad idea (see BashFAQ #6](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006). Also, naming a function `test` is bad because it overrides the standard built-in command by that name, so anything that tries to use the standard one will fail bizarrely. Finally, all-caps variable names are also best avoided, because there are a bunch of them with special meanings, and stepping on one of those can cause problems; it's better to use lower- or mixed-case variable names (unless you *want* the special meaning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, using variables as variable name produces surprising errors. You should be able to do this, but is requires a lot of escaping.

If you want to do this anyway, use `eval` (shell built-in):

```
test() {
eval $1=/home
}
```

As this is your first function, permit me to give you some additional hints.

- `test` is normally `/usr/bin/test`. If you use this as a function name, you will need to call `/usr/bin/test` by its full name. Better use `my_test` or something like that.
- Using a variable this way as lvalue ("left-value") is very rarely needed. So rarely that even shellcheck gets confused by it.

Comment: Wow! This was a really nice — and simple — way to get this idea to work while still explaining clearly, “This is not a great idea…”